# Vue 3 Convert scss to css

Tags: vuejs3, config, elixir-jason

I want to create a css file from scss and this file has to save the changes after i stop writing.

Where do I have to define it in Vite and how to do it?
I am using Vue 3.

Answer (score 0):

With Vite you can just `npm i -D sass`, create a `style.scss` file for example in the `src/assets/styles` folder.
If you need to add it globally, just include it in your `main.js/.ts` file like:

```js
@import "@/assets/styles/style.scss"
```

Otherwise add the same line in the component `<style lang="scss" scoped>` tag.

Comment: And how can I get change the path this file ?
I want create 2 folders
1) SCSS
2) CSS

Comment: When I'm done writing in scss, I would like the changes to be saved in css.

Comment: You won't get css files directly when typing, that's something that needs to be done in html files because they don't have a tool like vite, the css will be compiled together once you run `npm run build`